# Button inside GridView within UpdatePanel fires click event once

Tags: c#, events, gridview, postback

I have an update panel and a gridview. Within the gridview i have a button that has an onclick event handler (server side).

When i click the button the first time, it does a postback and the event handler is fired; but when i click the button the second time, there is not postback nor the firing of the event handler.

Can someone help me. What could be wrong? I've tried all sorts of things since yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebind the GridView in the ButtonClick/Command Event. If you are dynamically creating itemplates (With the Edit, Update, Cancel,... Commands) for the GridView you'll still need to do the same thing in the RowEditing, RowUpdating, RowCancelingEdit, respectively.